# PHP getting page title of XML Feed

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get the page title from XML Feeds.

I'm using `http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full` as an example and using the below code works with other sites but for `Lifehacker` it seems to ignore the closing `</title>` tag and console.log shows the entire content of the `xml` feed from after the opening `<title>`

```
function getTitle($Url){
        $str = file_get_contents($Url);
        if(strlen($str)>0){
            preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
            return $title[1];
        }
    }

$feed = 'http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/full';
$pagetitle = getTitle($feed);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing XML or HTML pages. Try this instead. Simpler and neater:

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');

var_dump((string)$feed->channel->title);
```

Comment: @Beardy Accept if you liked the answer ;)

Comment: I had to wait some time to accept ;) done now

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend against using regular expression for parsing XML documents. It's simply not suited for that.

Instead have a look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Now, what is wrong with your regular expression is that the star is greedy by default

```
preg_match("/\<title\>(.*?)<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
```

will get you what you are after. But keep in mind that your code will only return the first `title` element in the document.

More on regular expressions at this excellent reference site

http://www.regular-expressions.info/